# ASP.NET MVC4 WebApi parameter is null - on only one machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC4 WebApi project that is working fine on my development machine but is acting
strangely on a deployed server. Both boxes are Server 2008 with IIS 7.5

I have a single controller with a single Post method that takes a complex type as
a parameter. I am forcibly using the `XmlMediaType` formatter and `XmlSerialization` so
`HttpConfiguration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true` and the complex type is "old school" `XmlSerializable`.

For the same request my dev box correctly deserializes the XML in the body into
an instance of the complex type and the result returned to the client from the `Post` method  is correct. On the other machine the parameter instance is `null` on arrival in the `Post` method.

I have to reiterate that this is identical code and an identical request (except
for host name). That makes me think there has to be something environmentally 
different between the machines. Unfortunately after much searching I still have no idea what that might be.

I should also point out that if I modify my `Post` method to take a string parameter
and then do the deserialization myself internally the behavior on both boxes is the same and correct.

I have also implemented a custom serializer (`XmlFormatter.SetSerializer`) and again
the dev box works; the other produces a `null` parameter. Interestingly, when I log
the body of the request before deserialization in this case I see the same XML on both machines. It's just that one box drops the deserialzed value somewhere on the way to the `Post` method.

Can anyone offer some suggestions on how to proceed to troubleshoot this strange
behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ModelState on the controller. If deserialization fails for any reason, it gets recorded as a ModelState exception. It might help you at least figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Youssef, that definitely helped. The ModelState shows the non-working server complaining about the format of the posted xml - "There is an error in XML document (1, 14)". Interestingly, the root node is 13 characters long so whatever is "bad" is right after that. Even when I take out all the whitespace and the first child node is what's next I still get the complaint. And again, even at the wireshark level the EXACT same request works on my dev machine. Any other thoughts on why xml parsing would be different between machines?

Comment: Are you running the same version of the framework on both machines? Identical requests to servers running identical code on the same version of the framework and the same OS should have the same behavior. I'm as stumped as you are.

Comment: Very observant question! I neglected to include the detail that this solution contains an MS Portable Type Library project. With VS2010 PTL is an addin and servers without VS2010 and the addin need a framework update (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) to make them work like those with VS2010 and the addin. It was a long, painful slog to finally get to this point but the update fixed my problem. Thanks for keeping me on track!